# Error al instalar Java 9. Código de error 1624

Tags: java, windows, java-9

Saludos. Tengo una máquina con `Intel Core i5` corriendo [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7), traté de instalar el [jdk](/questions/tagged/jdk) de [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) con su respectivo [jre](/questions/tagged/jre) incluido. La parte de instalar las herramientas no me da problemas, pero al pasar al `JRE` me marca el siguiente error

> Java Install did not complete
>
> Error code: 1624

Y me dice que consulte en el [Centro de Ayuda de Java](http://java.com/es/download/help/), pero no encuentro el código de error en la primera lista que sale.

La ruta por defecto donde me pide instalarlo es `C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jre-9`.

¿A qué se debe el error y cómo puedo solventarlo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Aun no veo que haya documentacion de este error para `Java9`. Pero, segun la [documentacion de oracle](https://java.com/en/download/help/error_installshield.xml) el error `1624` para `Java7` y `Java8` tiene bastante pinta de ser lo mismo: **ha habido una instalación o actualización fallida y no permite la restauración del software por las *registry keys***.

> **SINTOMAS:**
>
> Durante la instalacion de Java desde Java.com, aparece un dialogo con uno de los siguientes codigos de error:
> Corrupt MSI, 25025, java_sp.dll is corrupt, 1035, 1305, 1311, 1324, 1327, 1335, 1600, 1601, 1606, **1624**, 1643, 1722, 1744, 1788, 2352, 2753, 2755 and 1618

Por lo que te recomiendo probar con la solución propuesta:

> **SOLUCIÓN:**
>
> - Prueba con la [Microsoft Fix it utility](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/en) para reparar las registry keys que previenen a algunos programas de ser completamente desinstalados y/o actualizados.
> - Descarga el instalador offline y ejecutalo.

Comment: Gracias, eso mismo intenté y la herramienta solo procedió a desinstalar las herramientas de jdk que ya había instalado, al tratar de instalar los resultados fueron los mismos, incluso bajé el jre aparte y obtuve los mismos resultados para las dos versiones la de 32 y 64 bits, no estoy seguro si se deba a que el jre embebido de la versión 7 está en el path

Answer (score -1):

Por seguridad java 7 pasa a java 8 trata de descargar la versión directamente de la página de oracle o en java com si tienes algun problema puedes consultar docs oracle com. Java 7 para Windows 7 funciona muy bien para empezar en la programación.

Comment: la pregunta dice Java 9, tengo instalado Java 9